# May I know which steps I have gone wrong I finding the variance?

Tags: solution-verification, variance

I want to find $\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[Y]$, where $Y=[\min(X,4)]$ and $$f(x)=\frac{1}{5}, 0<x<5.$$
So what I have done is to use this formulae:  $$\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[Y]=\mathbb{E}_I[\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[X\mid I]]+\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}_I[\mathbb{E}[X\mid I]],$$ and $I$ is an indicator function on whether the values of $x$ exceed $4.$  So, I have substituted all values:
$$\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[Y]=\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}_I[2,4]+\mathbb{E}_I[1.333333,0]$$
and we got
$$\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[Y]=4.3.$$

May I know which step I have gone wrong, thank you

Comment: It’s probably easier to use that $Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$ and calculate directly.

Comment: Eric, thank you so much for your reply, it is definitely easier, but I want to check which part of my solution has gone wrong, since it confuses me for a whole day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell where you went wrong since there is not much of your work shown. Here are the values I get

---

$$
\text{Var}(Y|X\le4)=\frac43\text{ with probability }\frac45
$$
$$
\text{Var}(Y|X\gt4)=0\text{ with probability }\frac15
$$
$$
\text{E}_I\!\left(\text{Var}(Y|I)\right)=\frac43\cdot\frac45+0\cdot\frac15=\boxed{\frac{16}{15}}
$$

---

$$
\text{E}(Y|X\le4)=2\text{ with probability }\frac45
$$
$$
\text{E}(Y|X\gt4)=4\text{ with probability }\frac15
$$
$$
\text{Var}_I\!\left(\text{E}(Y|I)\right)=\left(2^2\cdot\frac45+4^2\cdot\frac15\right)-\left(2\cdot\frac45+4\cdot\frac15\right)^2=\boxed{\frac{16}{25}}
$$

---

$$
\text{Var}(Y)=\frac{16}{15}+\frac{16}{25}=\boxed{\frac{128}{75}}
$$

Comment: From first principles: $$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(Y) &=\mathsf{Var}(\min\{X,4\})\\[1ex]&=\int_0^4\tfrac {x^2}5\mathrm d x+\int_4^5\tfrac {4^2}5\mathrm d x -\left(\int_0^4\tfrac 15 x\mathrm d x+\int_4^5\tfrac 45\mathrm d x\right)^2\\[1ex]&=\tfrac{64}{15}+\tfrac {16}5-\left(\tfrac{8}{5}+\tfrac 45\right)^2\\[1ex]&=\tfrac{128}{75}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I have realised where I went wrong